# SonarQube Plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to run sonar analysis and the execution is failing.The error I am seeing :-

### Using build-wrapper output: /Users/../out/build-wrapper-dump.json

14:26:01 14:23:02.369 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
14:26:01 14:23:02.369 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:26:01 14:23:02.369 INFO: Total time: 28.484s
14:26:01 14:23:02.503 INFO: Final Memory: 83M/1248M

---

14:26:01 14:23:02.503 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
14:26:01 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/.../app/build-wrapper-dump.json (No such file or directory)

In the sonar project properties I specified sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=app/out

Comment: What version of SonarQube do you use? Mention also the version numbers of the relevant plugin

Comment: Build Wrapper 3.6